Regex to extract data between certain dashes
I have the following string:
Prefix/Product-[1stMod-]SubProduct-2ndMod-Patch

I am trying to extract from the above:
[1stMod-]SubProduct

where '1stMod-' may or may not exist
and
2ndMod-Patch

where '2ndMod-' does actually exist.
As such, '[1stMod-]SubProduct' is between the first dash and the second to last dash and '2ndMod-Patch' is after the second to last dash through the end.

If your regex engine supports \K (e.g, Perl, PCRE, Ruby), you could match the regular expression
^[^-]*-\K(?:\[[^\]]+\])?[^-]+(?=-)|[^-\[\]]+(?=-[^-]*$)

Demo
The expression can be broken down as follows.
^           # match beginning of string
[^-]*-      # match >= 0 chars other than '-' followed by '-'
\K          # reset the start of the match and discard 
            # previously-matched chars
(?:         # begin a non-capture group
  \[        # match '['
  [^\]]+    # match > 0 chars other than ']'
  \]        # match ']'
)?          # end the non-capture group and make it optional
[^-]+       # match > 0 chars other than '-'
(?=-)       # positive lookahead asserts match is followed by '-'
|           # or
[^-\[\]]+   # match > 0 chars other than '-', '[' and ']' 
(?=-[^-]*$) # positive lookahead asserts match is followed by '-'
            # then >= 0 chars other than '-' then end of string


^[^-]*-(.*)-([^-]*-[^-]*)$

Explanation:

^[^-]* matches everything up to the first dash
- skips over that first dash
(.*)- captures everything in the middle, except the dash
([^-]*-[^-]*)$ captures everything after the 2nd-to-last dash


/(\[\S+-\]\w+|\[\.*-\]\w+)-(\S+-\S+)/gm

\[\S+-\]\w+ - looks for your "1stMod-" like string if exist
\[\.*-\]\w+ - if not exist
(\S+-\S+)  - looks for your "2ndMod-Patch" from second to last dash.
you can test your string here https://regex101.com/

Use regex (REGEX FLAGS: global & case-ignore):
[^\-]?\w+Mod\-\S\w+

where regex pattern:

output:

Test regex: https://regex101.com/

Add alternative regex (Best Solution):
(?<![^-])[^-]+Mod\-[^-]+[^-]+

Test regex: https://regex101.com/
